# Who/what chooses which slit to go through?

Tags: experimental-physics, photons

Since the observer has what seems to be a causal effect on the collapse of the  light wave into a particular photon- which in turn passes through one slit or the other in the doublee-slit experiment, does the conscious observer have any control on which slit the photon passes through? If not what causes the “choice” as to which slit the photon passes through?

Comment: This is a *very* popular question. Look up basic discussions about the double slit experiment. It is experimentally proven that nobody chooses the slit. It's random.

Comment: Particles moving toward a double slit exist in a superposition of all possible paths which the particle can take. The particle exists as a 'probability wave', where which it can go through both slits simultaneously and interfere with itself, producing the interference pattern. Observation collapses this probability wave into what we expect to observe classically. The randomness disappears of we are to observe which slit a particle went through. This gives a definite position, as opposed to the superposition of the particle not being observed.

Comment: It goes thru both simultaneously. The wave function becomes a superposition of the two possible options. It will only select a hole if you try to measure it by placing a detector in a hole, or covering one up, etc. it's what QM does: it propagates where it can, but trying to measure it will give you a yes or not, randomly, i.e. 50% of the time

Answer (score 0):

> Since the observer has what seems to be a causal effect on the collapse of the light wave into a particular photon-

This is a misconception. The experimenter/observer sets up the experiment: :

a)two slits at a distance of d between them and a width of w"

b)a beam of electrons that can be sent perpendicular to the plane of the slits

c)a sensitive screen at a distance d2 from the slits and parallel to the plane of the slits.

Where the observer experimenter enters is in sending off electrons one at a time and recording the footprint on the screen.

[Here is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) what the observer sees in accumulated single electron releases, (electrons because they are simpler in setting up an experiment particularly a screen):

[image: doublslele]

The causal effect of the observer is in setting up the experiment and recording the data. It is the solution of the behavior of the electrons in the quantum mechanical problem " electron impinging on double slit" that determines the distribution on the screen, i.e. gives the probability amplitude which obviously is not random, as the screen would have uniform hits.

> does the conscious observer have any control on which slit the photon passes through? If not what causes the “choice” as to which slit the photon passes through

No. The experiment can be done by robots, no consciousness needed. The only decisions are in the designe of the experimental setup .